# Execute batch of commands in a large script as form of queue (cron)

Tags: php, shell, batch-file, nginx, cron

I am making a remote fileuploading script which uploads a single or multiple chosen files to multiple filehosts, I am doing this by some cli script and as such all my main commands are executed using exec function. As such what I do is create my commands as per user input from one php file and save the commands in a .json file.
Then I have a separate file to be run manually or via cron to execute those batch of commands per json file. However sometimes if I input 50 files at once with 3 filehosts, commands to be executed are almost 100-150+ and manytimes due to nginx/php timeout or other such reasons the CLI script simply stops or suspends midway and then I have to restart whole batch and reupload all files again rather then the point where it ended/suspended.
Is there a better way to manage this type of long command queue and possibly resume it from where it last suspended or aborted ?
One way I thought is rather then creating all commands in a single json file, I create one file each for each command and save it in a new folder created for that queue, then the cron script picks one command file, executes it, if its success, deletes the file and selects next file (using loop)

Is that the only best option I can have ?

Comment: You should split that wall of text into smaller chunks to make it easier to read, for starters.

Comment: @JamesG. I am more used to normal tags and codes so getting a bit confused of how markcodes work here

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini to increase max execution time or the function set_time_limit